# IEnumerable<T> VS IList<T> VS IQueryable<T>

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, json

New to the MVC.net scene (and .net for that matter), but seems I find a wide array of options when wanting to populate a "list" with data.   In my case at the moment, I'd like to populate a list from a select query of items and render the results in JSON for output, so bear with me....

So, my viewmodel class is something like :

```
[Serializable()]
public class TFSquery 
{
    public int MsgUid { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateStamp { get; set; }    
}
```

And then I'd like to populate it with my query output:

```
List<TFSquery> z = (from msg in _DB.Msg 
                    select new { msg.MsgUID, msg.CreateStamp }).ToList();
```

Then would I loop the output into my List so that I can then output in my Json return string?  And when I use a **LIST** VS **IENUMERABLE** VS **IQUERYABLE**??

```
return Json(new { Result = z }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

My rules of thumb:

- Use a List when you have to add, remove, or refer to an item by index.
- Use a `IQueryable` when you have to run ad-hoc queries against it.
- Use `IEnumerable` by default.

It looks like you're already doing the query "in" your database, so I'd suggest using the simplest version: `IEnumerable` to simply be able to loop through the results.

Comment: Actually if possible, the `var` keyword should used in this case, then you don't have to worry about casting the type anywhere. Just change it to `var z = ...`  without the `ToList()` at the end. This will probably keep it `IQueryable` but that inherits from `IEnumerable` anyway.

Comment: ICollection of T when adding / removing, IList of T (or T[]) when indexing is required also.  Most things get away with just IEnumerable of T, and this is great to expose in public interfaces.  I rarely use List any more.

Answer (score 10):

If your new to .NET and C# I'd spend some time researching and becoming knowledgeable about what the different collection types are, how they differ, and when to use them.  You'll use collections so often it you cannot afford to have a "simple one liner" summary understanding like the other answerers posted.

Here is a good guide on .NET collection types:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ytkdh4s.aspx

IQueryable is its own special beast and deserves its own guide:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable.aspx

Comment: +1 The best answer is often the one which directs to the appropriate source. Thanks for posting the MSDN link!!

Answer (score 3):

Each interface has its own set of uses.

IQueryable is for deferred queries (that is, it saves the query but only executes it when it is enumerated)

IEnumerable can be enumerated and that's it.

IList can have items added and removed.

Comment: IEnumerable is also deferred execution.

Comment: `IEnumerable` can be used for deferred execution too.  For example, see [`Enumerable.Reverse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497.aspx).  It returns an `IEnumerable<TSource>`, but the actual reversal isn't started until the first element is enumerated.