# Why does IQueryable<> fail to generate a FK during Code First Migrations?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-migrations

Given:

```
public class Department
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IQueryable<Person> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

When I run **Update-Database -Verbose** in the Package Manager Console I get a SQL `[Person]` table with 2 columns:  Id, FullName.  If I update `Department.Employees` to:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<Person> Employees { get; set; }//or List, ICollection
```

then I get a `[Person]` table with 3 columns: Id, FullName, Department.

Why is it that `IQueryable` does not generate a relationship between Employee and Department?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246116/list-vs-ienumerable-vs-iqueryable-when-defining-navigation-property