# Using the ODATA $expand query option with WebAPI and a ViewModel

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323545/odata-expand-dtos-and-entity-framework) is very similar but does not give me what I need.

I am using Entity Framework 6.  My database has two tables, Customers and CustomerTypes.  I have created a ViewModel for each.  A customer can have a type:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public CustomerTypeViewModel CustomerType { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerTypeViewModel
{
    public int CustomerTypeID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerTypeDescription { get; set; }
}
```

I have a Customer controller which exposes an odata action method with a return type of IQueryable:

```
[HttpPost, Queryable(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
    public IQueryable<CustomerViewModel> GetCustomersMatchingCriteria([FromBody]ODataActionParameters parameters)
    {
        var criteria = (CustomerMassUpdateCriteriaViewModel)parameters["Criteria"];

        return Common.Customers.GetCustomerMassUpdateCriteriaResults(criteria,
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CLIENT_ID"]).Select(
            c => new CustomerViewModel()
            {
                CustomerID = c.CustomerID,
                CustomerName = c.CustomerName,
                CustomerType = new CustomerTypeViewModel() 
                {
                    CustomerTypeDescription = c.CustomerType.CustomerTypeDescription
                }
            });
    }
```

The Common.Customers.GetCustomerMassUpdateCriteriaResults method just returns an IQueryable of Customer, which is the actual entity.

The problem is, when calling this controller method with the following query string options:

```
$expand=CustomerType
$select=CustomerID,CustomerName,CustomerType/CustomerTypeDescription
```

This exception is thrown:

*The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type
'application/json; charset=utf-8'.","type":"System.InvalidOperationException"*

*The argument to DbIsNullExpression must refer to a primitive, enumeration or reference type.*

Removing the $expand option and the associated CustomerType/CustomerTypeDescription property from the $select list produces no error.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, here.  Any ideas?

**1st EDIT:**

Enumerating the results via the ToList() extension method and returning IEnumerable rather than IQueryable successfully expands the CustomerType navigation property, but my ODATA $select list is no longer respected at the database level.  Doesn't that defeat the purpose of using ODATA?

Comment: Did you end up with a solution for this? I'm still trying to sort this out.

Comment: @Josh, no, I didn't.  What I ended up doing was creating a more-specific viewmodel (or dto or whatever your case may be) for my need.  I was needing access to a property of a nested property, and it would be nice to get that working with "$expand", but instead I ended up just sticking that property on my main viewmodel and abandoned both the "$expand" option and the nested property.  I had to rethink some things architecturally because of this and I don't really like this solution, but apparently it's the only option I have as of now.

Answer (score 0):

Exception :

> The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for
>   content type 'application/json;
>   charset=utf-8'.","type":"System.InvalidOperationException"

per my knowledge is due to how request is reaching for OData formatting. The request should come to OData route for formatting. If you could move *GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnableOData()* before *RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes* and *WebApiConfig.Register* in global.asax could help.

Comment: From what I understand, the Queryable(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All) attribute should do the same thing at a more local level, but I did attempt to try your suggestion, and found that the EnableOData() method is not a member of GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.  Perhaps it's not available in WebAPI 5.0?