# WCF Data Services, DTO, and Entity Framework: The argument to DbIsNullExpression must refer to a primitive, enumeration or reference type

Tags: linq, entity-framework, odata, wcf-data-services, projection

I'm having a strange issue with $select in WCF Data Services combined with Entity Framework. **The Entity Framework entities are not being directly exposed by the service.** Rather, EF is being queried, and the results are being projected onto a DTO that IS being exposed.

Here is an example of queries that are working great, all the way down to properly formed queries in the database:

> /Test.svc/Files
>
> /Test.svc/Files?$filter=Name eq 'sample'

But this will NOT work:

> /Test.svc/Files?$select=Id

It throws this exception within the EntityFramework code base:

> The argument to DbIsNullExpression must refer to a primitive, enumeration or reference type.

...at this point in the call stack:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.ExpressionBuilder.DbExpressionBuilder.ValidateIsNull(DbExpression argument, Boolean allowRowType)

See below for details the entities in question. The IQueryable property is on the data source container (implementing IUpdatable), which is being used by the service.

- **File** is the entity framework object being pulled by dbContext.Files
- **EdmFile** is the DTO that I am projecting to, and exposing via the OData service.

Here is the IQueryable exposed by my data container:

```
public IQueryable<EdmFile> Files
{
    get
    {

        var files = dbContext.Files //EF collection of File
            .Select(f => new EdmFile() { Id = f.Id, Name = f.Name });

        return files; //return projection onto EdmFile
    }
}
```

**If I return files.ToList(), the $select will work.** However, the IQueryable will then be prematurely enumerated and ALL of the files (ignoring any requested $filter, etc.) will be retrieved from the database.

Here is the entity/DTO I am actually exposing:

```
[DataServiceKey("Id")]
public class EdmFile
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the Entity Framework entity:

```
public partial class File
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried repeatedly Googling this and perusing SO, but am not able to get anywhere with the results. Any help would be appreciated on this!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what version of EntityFramework you are usinge, but it looks like this issue was fixed in EntityFramework 6.1.0

Here is the issue on codeplex: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/826

Here is the SO question and answer that helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25320462/466100